# display records in a tree view

Tags: database, data-structures, treeview

I'm having a table with the following data

```
Col1  Col2

---------------

P     null

C1     P

C2     P

C11    C1

C12    C1

C21    C2
```

Col2 indicates the parent column.

I want to display the data in the tree form

```
P    
|_C1
|  |_C11
|  |_C12
|_C2
   |_C21
```

Is there any tool/program that displays database records in the tree format?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle:

Try [hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries003.htm#i2053935). Use `LEVEL` and `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` pseudo columns to decide if leading lines need to be drawn and how.

Something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEVEL = 1
            THEN col1
            ELSE LPAD( '_' || col1, ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 4, '|  ' )
       END output
FROM   tab1
CONNECT BY PRIOR col1 = col2
START WITH col2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: No, it won't work as expected. Vertical lines will be drawn even if not necessary, e.g. when there is no further sibling one level up but there is two level up.